# Elixir - How do I manage routes using Cowboy (and nothing else)?

Tags: http, elixir, cowboy

I'm restricted to only using Cowboy for a web server that handles a JSON REST API. I need to be able to use only Cowboy + whatever the language capabilities are to manage and process different and variable routes, as well as using the GET values.

I'm getting the path as explained in the following routine:

```
def handle(req, router) do
  headers = [{"content-type", "application/json"}]
  {path, req}  = :cowboy_req.path(req)
  {:ok, resp} = :cowboy_req.reply(200, headers, router.call(path), req)
  {:ok, resp, router}
end
```

And ultimately `route.call(path)` calls the following:

```
defp serve("/call/[:thing]") do
  list = [path: "oy"]
  IO.puts :thing
  {status, result} = JSON.encode(list)
  result
end
```

By itself, `serve("/call")` returns the JSON without issues, but trying to request any other route under `/call` to the server, makes it answer with the `404` response (already handled by me).

What's the best approach when handling these dynamic routes? Bear in mind that I'm delimited to only using Cowboy and nothing else.

Comment: You say that you are restricted to use only Cowboy, but throwing Plug in the mix would make this so much easier. Just sayin'.

Comment: I know. I can try to talk my way into using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not very clear - how did you start the server? More specifically, how did you setup your router? This seems to be the problem here, I'm guessing you made a route only for `/call`.

You'd need something like this:

```
dispatch_config = :cowboy_router.compile([{:_, [{"/call/[:thing]", YourHandlerModule, []}]}])
{ :ok, _ } = :cowboy.start_http(:http,
                                100,
                                [{:port, 8080}],
                                [{ :env, [{:dispatch, dispatch_config}]}]
                                )
```

The path `/call/[:thing]` should be specified at the router, not inside your handler.

Answer (score 0):

I found one simple solution by only using Cowboy and Elixir:

```
def call(conn) do
  serve(conn.req_path, conn)
end

defp serve(<< "/call/", name::binary >>, conn) do
  list = conn.req_qs
  IO.puts name
  {_, result} = JSON.encode(list)
put_resp_body(conn, result)
```

If you do it like this, all subsequent routes stay in `rest`. A simple split would do. `conn` carries the query string, so I can get the values from there.